# How many requests/characters can we send for a minute in a request in Google Translation API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translation-api

I am sending request to

`https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=mykey`

The body of request is

```
{
    "q": ["Some characters here", "and here"],
    "from": "en",
    "target": "de"
}
```

Sometimes it allows me to do more requests with the same body (<5K characters), but I can't find the same exact number of requests or characters to send per minute?

Answer (score 1):

[Cloud translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas#request_quotas) quotas are divided into each version of the API that you are using, which are the next ones;

> Requests for getting supported languages (v2 and v3 combined) per
> minute per project 600 requests
>
> v2 requests per minute per project† 300,000 requests
>
> v2 requests per minute per project per user*† up to the v2 per project
> limit
>
> v3 requests per minute per project† 6000 requests
>
> v3 requests per minute per project per user*† up to the v3 per project limit
>
> Total number of v3 batch translation requests (text and
> documents) per day per project. Unlimited

(*) Per user quotas apply to the number of requests that an end user, who is using a client application, can make per minute. When you use a service account, the service account's identity is the user for quota purposes. If you use Cloud Translation - Basic and an API key, Cloud Translation uses the client's IP address to enforce this limit.

(†) Applies to all Cloud Translation method calls except for the translateText, detectLanguage, translateDocument, and getSupportedLanguages methods, which have their own request or content quotas.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using it to translate text namely translateText method. I cannot make more than 3 requests if text is of 8K characters length. I wanted to know how many requests am I allowed to make if  the request for ex is less than 5K. Any exact number if you can tell me?

Comment: No problem, the recommended maximum length for each request is 5000 characters, if you found my answer useful, I would be very glad if you up voted it and marked it as accepted :)